# styling a hover statement in SVG

Tags: css, if-statement, svg, hover

I'm planning a web 'menu' based on this SVG illustation:
[the principle of my idea; a circle styled as being active, a circle styled as hover and an accompanying stroke that also needs to be styled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H397o.png)

[image]

As I read the specs of an SVG file, I cant work with if-then statements.

I'm struggling with how to solve the hover styling of the stroke that is linking the two circles. In other words, how do I style an element in an SVG file when the element is

1. outside the trigger element

AND

2. based on the currently active page/active circle

I would appreciate help to find a way to do this - or alternative ways.

Thanks.

Comment: If a programming assignment seems too complex; simplify it. Start with 2 circles and use JavaScript to draw a line between them.

Comment: Have you investigated using a bit of Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done fairly simply.  But it requires a little javascript.

Here's a simplified example with just three circles.  Hopefully it should be obvious how to add the other two circles and the rest of the lines.  The JS and CSS should work as is for any number of circles and lines.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

    var  allCircles = document.querySelectorAll("circle");

    // Add an click handler to every circle that
    // adds the class "active" to the clicked circle.
    allCircles.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
        element.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseoverHandler);
        element.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutHandler);
    });
    
});


function  clickHandler(evt) {
    // Clear current selection (remove class "active" from any circle)
    allCircles.forEach((circle) => circle.classList.remove("active"));
    // Mark clicked circle selected
    evt.target.classList.add("active");
    // Clear any currently highlighted lines
    clearHighlightedLines();
}


function  mouseoverHandler(evt) {
    let activeCircle = document.querySelector("circle.active");
    let hoveredCircle = evt.target;
    if (activeCircle && (activeCircle != hoveredCircle)) {
        // Get the line that has classes matching both the actibve and hovered circle
        let line = document.querySelector("line."+activeCircle.id+"."+hoveredCircle.id);
        // Add the class "highlight" to that line
        if (line)
            line.classList.add("highlight");
    }
}


function  mouseoutHandler(evt) {
    clearHighlightedLines();
}


function  clearHighlightedLines() {
    // Find the line with class "highlight" (if any)
    var line = document.querySelector("line.highlight");
    // Remove the class "highlight"
    if (line)
        line.classList.remove("highlight");
}
```

```css
#c3 {
  fill: maroon;
}

#c4 {
  fill: steelblue;
}

#c5 {
  fill: rebeccapurple;
}

circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
}

circle.active {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
}

line {
  stroke: gold;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

line.highlight {
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  
  <!-- line from c3 to c4 -->
  <line x1="75" y1="40" x2="25" y2="70" class="c3 c4"/>

  <!-- line from c3 to c5 -->
  <line x1="75" y1="40" x2="57" y2="70" class="c3 c5"/>

  <!-- line from c4 to c5 -->
  <line x1="25" y1="70" x2="57" y2="70" class="c4 c5"/>


  <circle id="c3" cx="75" cy="40" r="10"/>

  <circle id="c4" cx="25" cy="70" r="10"/>

  <circle id="c5" cx="57" cy="70" r="10"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, Poul. It's the first time I have asked a question in here and I really thought it was a long shot. But you nailed it - fantastic -  I'm so happy.

Comment: I'm basically wondering why this answer/solution can run on this page, but not when copied to an HTML file with a link to the external javascript file.
It seems to be the javascript that doesn't do its magic and I have read that scripts are not parsed to the browser when the code is inside the SVG file. I have tried different ways to load it - but nothing works. Any ideas?
What is working is up to the point where the circle gets highlighted with a grey border. When I press the state doesn't change to a black border. And the rest isn't working either...

Comment: The first section of Javascript (the bit before the functions) needs to be run after the DOM is ready.  I've updated my answer to show how to do that.

Comment: Sorry. I must have forgotten to save.  Fixed now.

Comment: Hi @PaulLeBeau. I'm having some issues with the `clickHandler` because the .active class is not added - please see my other question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68330400/svg-display-alt-text-in-p-tag-on-hover). Here the active class is added but with the same script and the same SVG on my test site is not getting the same result. 
The feedback I'm getting is that it is only working because all the links are href="#0". The links on the test site are not determined correct and the selected circle doesn't get the “active”-class as it is supposed to get when a new page loads.

Comment: @JanMagnussen Sorry. I am not understanding what the problem is. You might need to ask a new question. Why are you using `<a>` elements anyway? They don't seem to have a purpose.

Comment: OK I have written a new question - see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68621656/current-page-focus-style-not-set-correctly-with-the-javascript-what-is-wrong). The `<a>` is in the SVG because each circle is a bottom to another page, I didn't think about the issues related to using #0 and a real page URL. But the `:focus` is not determined correctly. It could probably also be because I describe the solution as the circle should be 'active' - which wasn't meant to be a css-definition.