# javascript animated SVG not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, svg

My javascript animated SVG not working in WordPress. Can anybody help with the best practice of how to make an animated SVG work?

My first thought is - is it not working because of the security of having javascript inside an SVG file...

The file works as-is:
https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/stack-test-menu_3x.svg

My SVG file looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 912.83 882.07">

   <defs>
    <style>
 :root {
        --color-1: #F2B705;
        --color-2: #C30F0E;
        --color-3: #264ABA;
        --color-4: #009CD2;
        --color-5: #E25727;

        
        --color-11: #C29204;
        --color-22: #990B0B;
        --color-33: #172E73;
        --color-44: #006B8E;
        --color-55: #BA4620;
  }
#c1 {
  fill: var(--color-1);
}
#c2 {
  fill: var(--color-2);
}
#c3 {
  fill: var(--color-3);
}

#c4 {
  fill: var(--color-4);
}

#c5 {
  fill: var(--color-5);
}
        .cls-7 {
        fill: #a1ac75;
      }
        
circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-width: 11.5;
}

circle.active {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 11.5;
}

line {
  stroke: gold;
  stroke-width: 4;
}

line.highlight {
  stroke: black;
}
    </style>
    
  </defs>
    <polygon id="fem-kant" class="cls-7" points="456.29 7.49 898.87 329.05 729.82 849.33 182.76 849.33 13.71 329.05 456.29 7.49"/>

      <line class="c3 c5" x1="656.32" y1="748.57" x2="133.5" y2="368.62"/>
      <line class="c2 c4" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="779.33" y2="368.43"/>
      <line class="c1 c4" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="457.43" y2="133.5"/>
      <line class="c1 c3" x1="457.43" y1="133.5" x2="657.03" y2="748.57"/>
      <line class="c5 c2" x1="133.5" y1="368.62" x2="779.33" y2="368.43"/>
      <line class="c1 c2" x1="779.33" y1="368.43" x2="457.43" y2="133.5"/>
      <line class="c2 c3" x1="779.33" y1="368.43" x2="657.03" y2="748.57"/>
      <line class="c3 c4" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="657.03" y2="748.57"/>
      <line class="c4 c5" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="133.5" y2="368.62"/>
      <line class="c5 c1" x1="133.5" y1="368.62" x2="457.43" y2="133.5"/>

  <a href="#0">
      <circle id="c1" cx="455.9" cy="133.5" r="133"/>
        </a>
  <a href="#0">
      <circle id="c2" cx="779.33" cy="368.43" r="133"/>
      </a>
  <a href="#0">
      <circle id="c3" cx="656.32" cy="748.57" r="133"/>
      </a>
  <a href="#0">
      <circle id="c4" cx="256.18" cy="748.57" r="133"/>
      </a>
  <a href="#0">
      <circle id="c5" cx="133.5" cy="368.62" r="133"/>
      </a>

<script>
<![CDATA[
var  allCircles = document.querySelectorAll("circle");

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

    // Add an click handler to every circle that
    // adds the class "active" to the clicked circle.
    allCircles.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
        element.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseoverHandler);
        element.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutHandler);
    });
    
});

function  clickHandler(evt) {
    // Clear current selection (remove class "active" from any circle)
    allCircles.forEach((circle) => circle.classList.remove("active"));
    // Mark clicked circle selected
    evt.target.classList.add("active");
    // Clear any currently highlighted lines
    clearHighlightedLines();
}

function  mouseoverHandler(evt) {
    let activeCircle = document.querySelector("circle.active");
    let hoveredCircle = evt.target;
    if (activeCircle && (activeCircle != hoveredCircle)) {
        // Get the line that has classes matching both the actibve and hovered circle
        let line = document.querySelector("line."+activeCircle.id+"."+hoveredCircle.id);
        // Add the class "highlight" to that line
        if (line)
            line.classList.add("highlight");
    }
}

function  mouseoutHandler(evt) {
    clearHighlightedLines();
}

function  clearHighlightedLines() {
    // Find the line with class "highlight" (if any)
    var line = document.querySelector("line.highlight");
    // Remove the class "highlight"
    if (line)
        line.classList.remove("highlight");
}
    //]]>
    </script>
</svg>
```

But the javascript is not working and the SVG file looks like this in WordPress:
https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/sample-page/

If the script should be outside the SVG file - can I link to the script placed at the root of the site. What would a link inside an SVG file look like?

Answer (score 0):

I made a little mistake in [my answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68102766/1292848). The

```
var  allCircles = document.querySelectorAll("circle");
```

part should be inside the `DOMContentLoaded` event.  I believe that if you fix that, it will make a difference.

Comment: Hi Poul. Thanks for being there.
No the animation stop working with that change.

Comment: We might be hitting a wall where I can help, because I am not familiar with the details of WordPress. Depending on how the SVG is included in the page, you may have to initialise the script a different way.  When I manually edited the live page, it started working. So it appears the script is not being initialised at the right time.

Comment: The script is now being loaded. My worries that WordPress was the problem is now eliminated.
The SVG file is placed as inline and the javascript and the css is placed outside the SVG file. This all fine.
The javascript is handling the links differently when the ‘#0’ is replaced with real ‘/zxy’ links - any idea why that is?
I would like to be able to style the circle that is active (= active page).  I was trying this:

`element.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  event.target.style.border = ‘black;
}, true);`
... but that didn’t do the trick. How do I do that?

Comment: There is no need to use `<a>` elements.  They come with their own default browser behavious that can interfere with your own.  Just apply the click handlers to the circles directly.  Or if you need to wrap the circles, you can always replace the `<a>` with a simple group `<g>` elements.

Comment: If the reason you are using `<a>` is to get the finger pointer icon, then you can just add `cursor: pointer` to the circle CSS instead.