# current page focus style not set correctly with the javascript, what is wrong

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm working on a project where an SVG illustration is essential for the understanding of the content of the website.

The SVG file is supposed to be working as an animated menu, where each circle is a button linking to another parent page. The SVG file is inserted on the page as raw code.

I'm seeking help to solve these issues:

1. The current page, or the corresponding circle in the SVG file, is not defined in javascript in a way that the circle in `:focus` mode - gets the style with a border
2. this problem is because the “active” item/page is not determined correctly in javascript, the line between the circles are not style black
3. The circle stays in focus mode (styled with a border) when the user is on one of the child-pages

[image of the result I'm looking for, looks likes this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tPNd.png)

The snippet below is with the `href` links from my test site. The javascript works when the `href` is #0 and we don't leave the page, but that's not the intention with this menu.

```js
let allCircles = document.querySelectorAll("circle");
// Add an click handler to every circle that
// adds the class "active" to the clicked circle.
allCircles.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
  element.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseoverHandler);
  element.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseoutHandler);
});

function clickHandler(evt) {
  // Clear current selection (remove class "active" from any circle)
  allCircles.forEach((circle) => circle.classList.remove("active"));
  // Mark clicked circle selected
  evt.target.classList.add("active");
  // Clear any currently highlighted lines
  clearHighlightedLines();
}


function mouseoverHandler(evt) {
  let activeCircle = document.querySelector("circle.active");
    document.querySelector("#pagetitle").innerHTML = evt.target.getAttribute('alt')

  let hoveredCircle = evt.target;
  if (activeCircle && (activeCircle != hoveredCircle)) {
    // Get the line that has classes matching both the actibve and hovered circle
    let line = document.querySelector("line." + activeCircle.id + "." + hoveredCircle.id);
    // Add the class "highlight" to that line
    if (line)
      line.classList.add("highlight");
  }
}

function mouseoutHandler(evt) {
  clearHighlightedLines();
}

function clearHighlightedLines() {
  // Find the line with class "highlight" (if any)
  var line = document.querySelector("line.highlight");
  // Remove the class "highlight"
  if (line)
    line.classList.remove("highlight");
}
```

```css
:root {
        --color-1: #F2B705;
        --color-2: #C30F0E;
        --color-3: #264ABA;
        --color-4: #009CD2;
        --color-5: #E25727;

        
        --color-11: #C29204;
        --color-22: #990B0B;
        --color-33: #172E73;
        --color-44: #006B8E;
        --color-55: #BA4620;
  }
#c1 {
  fill: var(--color-1);
}
#c2 {
  fill: var(--color-2);
}
#c3 {
  fill: var(--color-3);
}

#c4 {
  fill: var(--color-4);
}

#c5 {
  fill: var(--color-5);
}
.cls-7 {
fill: none
    ;
}

#c1.act {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 21.5;
}

#c1.active {
    stroke: var(--color-11);
    stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c2.active {
    stroke: var(--color-22);
    stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c3.active {
    stroke: var(--color-33);
    stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c4.active {
    stroke: var(--color-44);
    stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c5.active {
    stroke: var(--color-55);
    stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c1.circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-11);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c2.circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-22);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c3.circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-33);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c4.circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-44);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
#c5.circle:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-55);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}

circle.btn1:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-11);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
circle.btn2:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-22);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
circle.btn3:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-33);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
circle.btn4:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-44);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}
circle.btn5:hover:not(.active) {
  stroke: var(--color-55);
  stroke-width: 21.5;
}

line {
  stroke: #c1c1c1;
  stroke-width: 22;
}

line.highlight {
  stroke: black;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
}
#pagetitle {
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-10 -10 940 910">

   <defs>
    <style src="https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/wp-content/uploads/custom-css-js/svg-menu.css"></style>
    
  </defs>
       <polygon id="fem-kant" class="cls-7" points="456.29 7.49 898.87 329.05 729.82 849.33 182.76 849.33 13.71 329.05 456.29 7.49"/>

      <line class="c3 c5" x1="656.32" y1="748.57" x2="133.5" y2="368.62"/>
      <line class="c2 c4" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="779.33" y2="368.43"/>
      <line class="c1 c4" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="457.43" y2="133.5"/>
      <line class="c1 c3" x1="457.43" y1="133.5" x2="657.03" y2="748.57"/>
      <line class="c5 c2" x1="133.5" y1="368.62" x2="779.33" y2="368.43"/>
      <line class="c1 c2" x1="779.33" y1="368.43" x2="457.43" y2="133.5"/>
      <line class="c2 c3" x1="779.33" y1="368.43" x2="657.03" y2="748.57"/>
      <line class="c3 c4" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="657.03" y2="748.57"/>
      <line class="c4 c5" x1="258.55" y1="747.22" x2="133.5" y2="368.62"/>
      <line class="c5 c1" x1="133.5" y1="368.62" x2="457.43" y2="133.5"/>

<a href="https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/trans-disciplinary">
  <circle id="c1" class="btn1 btn" href="/trans-disciplinary" alt="Trans-disciplinary" cx="455.9" cy="133.5" r="133" data-Name="Trans-disciplinary" data-tabindex="1" />
</a>
<a href="https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/data-democracy">
<circle id="c2" class="btn2 btn" href="/data-democracy" alt="Data Democracy" cx="779.33" cy="368.43" r="133" data-Name="Data Democracy" data-tabindex="2" />
</a>
<a href="https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/cryptography-and-math">
<circle id="c3" class="btn3 btn" href="/cryptography-and-math" alt="Cryptography and Math" cx="656.32" cy="748.57" r="133" data-Name="Cryptography and Math" data-tabindex="3" />
</a>
<a href="https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/translation">
<circle id="c4" class="btn4 btn" href="/translation" alt="Translation" cx="256.18" cy="748.57" r="133" data-Name="Translation" data-tabindex="4" />
</a>
<a href="https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/application">
<circle id="c5" class="btn5 btn" href="/application" alt="Application" cx="133.5" cy="368.62" r="133" data-Name="Application" data-tabindex="5" />
</a>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/wp-content/uploads/custom-css-js/svg-menu.js"></script>

    </svg>
<div class="title">
    <p id="pagetitle"> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is still not quite clear to me. Can I assume that the same SVG is on all six pages (main + 5 child pages) and that you want to know how to get the SVGs on the child pages to show the correct state when they load?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And that the 3rd ( + 4th, 5th,etc) level child pages also show the state of the 1st level page (like www.123.com/**aaa(bold)**/bbb/ccc/ddd). I hope this makes it clear, otherwise ask.

Comment: When a page loads, you will need to initialise the SVG state based on which page you are on. The child pages obviously know which one they are.  Alternatively, you could make it automatic by storing the selected item in [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Then when a page loads, retrieve that value and initialise the menu with it.

Comment: I am not particularly used to working in Javascript and have not learned it as such. I read your message as there are two possible ways to go. Although I have tried to google the first alternative I have not seen anything that makes sense in this context. Conversely, I think (intuitively?) that `sessionStorage` seems like a solution but may not have the whole overview. What do you think is the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as below, and it should work (if I haven't messed anything up).

Change `clickHandler()` as follows:

```
function clickHandler(evt) {
  // Activate the circle
  activateCircle(evt.target.id);
  // Remember which one was clicked, so that we can
  // highlight the right one when we get to the subpage
  sessionStorage.setItem("selectedMenuId", evt.target.id);
}

function activateCircle(elementId)
{
  // Clear current selection (remove class "active" from any circle)
  allCircles.forEach((circle) => circle.classList.remove("active"));
  // Mark clicked circle selected
  document.getElementById(elementId).classList.add("active");
  // Clear any currently highlighted lines
  clearHighlightedLines();
}
```

And on the submenu pages **only**, include this extra little bit of JS.

```
//--- Initialise the menu -------------------------------------------
// Include this section on the subpages only!
document.querySelector("svg").addEventListener("load", () => {
  // Get the id of the menu item that was selected on the last page
  var activeId = sessionStorage.getItem("selectedMenuId");
  // Activate that circle
  if (activeId)
    activateCircle(activeId);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. It's not working right now. The active and I just have to clear that and doing it right: The "Initialise the menu" JS - it that suppose to be as is, or is it suppose to be part of the main [JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68102766/16288695)? Currently, I'm loading all my JS at the end of my body - is that also true for "Initialise the menu" JS? The whole shebang is not working [here](https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/), if you want to see.

Comment: * that suppose to be as is, or is it suppose to be part of the main JS?" It doesn't matter as long as it is run on the sub pages.  As for why your test site is not working: it's a bit hard to tell because it's all black. It seems like the CSS for the SVG is not loading.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to activate the CSS after a test - it is on now.

Comment: What may be happening is that the default handling of the `<a>` elements is preventing the click actions from being performed.  Try removing the `<a>` elements and instead redirect to your new page via JS. Use `window.location = whatever` to redirect.

Comment: OK. The 5 circles have now a `onclick` ala `onclick="goDatademocracy()"` with a JS `function  goDatademocracy() {
  location.href = "https://aau.gagarindigital.dk/data-democracy";
}` for each. The links are working but the .active class is still not added.

Comment: You've now got two click handlers. Try putting the `window.location=x` in the `clickHandler()` function.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add value to `windov.location`, as the value is a variable. Can you give a hint?