# How would a nested function look like in this clickHandler()?

Tags: javascript

I'm stalled with this `clicHandler()` from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68621656/current-page-focus-style-not-set-correctly-with-the-javascript-what-is-wrong):

```js
function clickHandler(evt) {
    // Activate the circle
    activateCircle(evt.target.id);
    // Remember which one was clicked, so that we can
    // highlight the right one when we get to the subpage
    sessionStorage.setItem("selectedMenuId", evt.target.id);
}
```

The problem is that there are 5 different circles, and I need the `clickHandler()` to know which one has been clicked and return the correct `activateCircle(evt.target.id)`.

I was thinking about something like this (I might be wrong):

```js
getElementById("c1").onclick = goTransdisciplinary () {
    location.href = "/trans-disciplinary";
};
getElementById("c2").onclick = goDatademocracy () {
    location.href = "/data-democracy";
};
getElementById("c3").onclick = goCryptography () {
    location.href = "/cryptography-and-math";
};
getElementById("c4").onclick = goTranslation () {
    location.href = "/translation";
};
getElementById("c5").onclick = goApplication () {
    location.href = "/application";
};
```

But how would a nested function look like?

Comment: Is my question too stupid, just some nonsense or is it unclear? Give me a hint. Please.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Can I entice you to help me again?